# is it valid to declare css variable in class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, css-variables

I did not see css variable declaration (syntax) like before,

generally i use css variable like using `:root{}`.. below code is difference...

after run webpack, below css  code i find...

is it valid syntax ? I am using vs code editor, editor does't show any error also..

**Or maybe I am wrong somewhere else, Just leave a comment..**

**Bootstrap Sass Imported**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

**Output CSS Syntax**

```
.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);
  margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / -2);
  margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / -2);
}
.row > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes it's valid ..

Comment: from the duplicate *Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with the normal inheritance and cascade rules*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are called [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

> Custom properties allow a value to be stored in one place, then referenced in multiple other places.

Note how `--bs-gutter-x` is reused in lines 7 and 8. The advantage is that you now only need to change the value in one place (line 2).